# Client- headers in a HTTP request

Tags: http-headers

Lately, I've been seeing headers such as:

```
Client-Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 15:20:02 GMT
Client-Peer: 64.64.64.64:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
```

On a apache 2 server with php 5.3.

What is the purpose / meaning of these headers, and where/when are they inserted into the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These HTTP headers are generated by [libwww-perl](http://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) - [LWP::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) (makes http requests / simulates web user agent) for debugging purposes and their meaning is exactly what their names imply.

References:

- http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=Client-Date+Client-Peer+Client-Response-Num&sbtn=Search
- [http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent)
- [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Proxy](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aProxy)

Comment: Thanks! I just realized that I only saw these using the HEAD script that came with perl. Hadn't thought they had been added in after the innitial request. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

They are non-standard http response headers and they can have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by any chance, using HTTP::Proxy? If you turn on `[client_headers`][1](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/HTTP-Proxy/HTTP/Proxy.html#client_headers) there, you get these headers.